# Estimation of order of decay of amplitude of solutions of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solutions of differential equations like $$D^2(y)=-x^{2n} y, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z},$$ are generally oscillating functions with increasing frequency as $x$ increases and simultaneously their amplitude gets reduced too.

- 1.How can i estimate the order at which the amplitude falls as $x$ gets large?
- 2.How does the zeros behave at large x?